# setting specific users as staff users with django ldap

Tags: django, ldap, django-authentication

I've successfully managed to get django-ldap working with my active directory server, however now I want to make certain users part of django's `staff` group.

I don't see how I can specify particular user accounts (is that possible?), so I decided to just allow anyone of a particular group:

```
# Set up the basic group parameters.
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("OU=mygroup,OU=users,DC=myserver",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=memberOf)"
)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = ActiveDirectoryGroupType()
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "OU=mygroup,OU=users,DC=myserver",
    "is_staff": "OU=mygroup,OU=users,DC=myserver",
}

# This is the default, but I like to be explicit.
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True

# Use LDAP group membership to calculate group permissions.
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True

# Cache group memberships for an hour to minimize LDAP traffic
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
```

Unfortunately this configuration doesn't work, here's the log entry:

```
CN=my_user,OU=mygroup,OU=users,DC=myserver is not a member of OU=mygroup,OU=users,DC=myserver
```

I don't really see what the problem is, since the group member ship is identical. Is it something about the `AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH` that is incorrectly configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group membership, as django-auth-ldap uses the term, doesn't have anything to do with directory tree structure. `CN=my_user,OU=mygroup,OU=users,DC=myserver` is not a member of `OU=mygroup,OU=users,DC=myserver` in this sense, it just happens to be a sub-DN. If you want to assign Django user properties based on arbitrary attributes (including DN), you can attach a signal handler to [django_auth_ldap.backend.populate_user](http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/#django_auth_ldap.backend.populate_user).